# Rearranging Cell Subviews When UITableViewCell Resizes

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UITableViewCell` that is implemented using storyboard that looks like:

[image]

Here is what the cell should look like without an image:

[image]

I have been fiddling with the constraints and banging my head trying to figure this out but have had no luck.  I have a pretty good understanding of constraints and how to add them programmatically but have had no luck with this specific problem and feel like I am just adding layout constraints to the cell willy-nilly with no logical thought process.  The cell represents a newsfeed post which may or may not have an image in the main image view at the top, and should behave as follows.  If the cell doesn't have an image in it the bottom bar with the like and comment counts, moves up to align with the top of the cell.  I achieved this behaviour by setting a constraint that kept the smaller image view, post title, post time and the post content a set distance away from the bottom of the cell.  This approach works and when the cell is resized in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method the subviews move appropriately.  The problem comes when the text in the post content is larger then a single line.  The height of the cell adjusts correctly but the top of the text view stays at the same location and grows downward and overflows into the next cell.  When I place the constraints to align the four subviews with the top of the cell I run into issues when there is no image and the post content is larger then a single line.  In this case, the cell resizes to be smaller than its original size and the subviews stay at the distance specified by the constraint. The smaller image, post title, time and content are clipped and don't display.  This is such an odd problem with so many different cases.  I have been working at this for almost two days and could really use someone else's thoughts on how to solve this issue.  I hope this isn't too confusing, thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is that small square image view supposed to be, and move? Is it supposed to overlap that larger image view? Does it always have an image, or is it blank sometimes too?

Comment: Also, when there is no image in the large image view, you want that bottom bar to be above the other content? At the top of the cell?

Comment: I edited the post and added an image of what the cell should look like without an image. @rdelmar

Comment: A couple of other questions. When you have the large image, is the small image view on top partially overlapping it? And what are Post Title, Post Time, and Post Content -- is that 3 labels, or a mixture of labels and text views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @rdelmar thanks for the solution! Eventually I ended up just designing two different cells  in the storyboard file with different reuse identifiers but the same subclass.  I then checked in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method if the cell had content or not, and assigned the correct identifier.  If this is the incorrect way of doing this, or will cause problems down the road please let me no in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I have one way to solve this, but I'm sure there are many others. I gave both image views a fixed height constraint. The small image view and the top label (Post Title) have fixed heights to the top of the cell -- both of these as well as the height constraint of the large image view have IBOutlets to them so they can be changed in code. The bottom label (Post Content) has its number of lines set to 0, and has an IBOutlet to its height constraint (all the labels had the standard 21 point height to start). In code, I check for the existence of an image at each indexPath, and change the constraints accordingly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"House.tiff"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = @[@{@"pic":image1, @"post":@"short post"},@{@"post":@"short post"},@{@"pic":image1, @"post":@"Long long post with some extra stuff, and even some more"},@{@"post":@"Long long post with some extra stuff, and even some more"}];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat ivHeight = (self.theData[indexPath.row][@"pic"])? 215 : 0; // 215 is the fixed height of the large image view
    CGSize labelSize = [self.theData[indexPath.row][@"post"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(152, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    return 140 + ivHeight + labelSize.height; // the 140 was determined empirically to get the right spacing between the 3 labels and the bottom bar
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = self.theData[indexPath.row][@"post"];
    cell.iv.image = self.theData[indexPath.row][@"pic"];
    if(self.theData[indexPath.row][@"pic"] == nil){
        cell.heightCon.constant = 0; // heightCon is the outlet to the large image view's height constraint
        cell.ivTopCon.constant = 8; // ivTopCon is the outlet to the small image view's spacing to the top of the cell
        cell.labelTopCon.constant = 8; // labelTopCon is the outlet to thetop label's spacing to the top of the cell
    }else{
        cell.heightCon.constant = 215; // this number and the following 2 are taken from the values in IB
        cell.ivTopCon.constant = 185;
        cell.labelTopCon.constant = 233;
    }
    CGSize labelSize = [self.theData[indexPath.row][@"post"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(152, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    cell.labelHeightCon.constant = labelSize.height;
    return cell;
}
```